# Calling a static function from a template parameter in a lambda function while ignoring default parameters

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

Ok, I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to mess with lambdas in templates.  VC++ has an odd quirk dealing with template parameters, but I found a workaround for calling a static function of a template parameter (T::magic in this example) by using the auto keyword.  However, I have hit another hitch.

Say I have one of many classes with a function "magic", and only the first 2 parameters matter for my call later.  It may or may not have some defaulted parameters after the first 2.  I don't really care about them for this application, I only need to call magic(start, otherthing).  Uhoh is one of these classes:

```
struct Uhoh
{
 static int magic(char* start, int otherthing, bool doom = false);
}
```

I do the call with this template.  I have to use a workaround of using the auto type to get T::magic for it to work in the lambda function.

```
template<typename T> void example()
{
 auto themagic = T::magic;

 std::function<int (char*)> test = [=](char* start) -> int
 {
  return themagic(start, 0);
 };

 test(0);
}
```

And then I call it or whatever.

```
int main()
{
 example<Uhoh>();
}
```

I get an error about "too few arguments for call", even though "magic" can take two arguments.  Now, I can't know for sure what the type will be for "otherthing" in any of the various "magic" functions.  All I know is that 0 will be a valid value.  Passing the type of whatever otherthing will be to the function "example" will be an extreme annoyance at best.

How can I properly type "themagic" so that VC++ doesn't throw an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auto themagic = T::magic;
```

Here the information that the third parameter of `T::magic` has default value is lost, as the type of `themagic` is deduced as `int (*)(char*, int, bool)`, which *cannot* have any default value for the third parameter. So you cannot call `themagic` with only two arguments. You've to pass third argument as well.

So do this:

```
std::function<int (char*)> test = [=](char* start) -> int
{
  return themagic(start, 0, false);
};
```

Please note that default-value for a function parameter is **not** a part of the function signature, which means when you write

```
auto themagic = T::magic;
```

then type of `themagic` **cannot** be deduced as `int (*)(char*, int, bool=false)`.

Comment: I get that.  I'm looking for a way of not losing it (probably using function<>?) but while simultaneously not knowing the type of the 2nd argument that I will be using.  The default parameters could vary with different "magic" functions.  I can't be setup for using just one instance of it.

Comment: @user173342" No. The function type cannot store that value.